# Update UI Immediately for Real-Time Processing

Tags: android, real-time

I am developing a real-time audio processing software which should update the UI in at least 100ms from the worker thread.
However, this appears harder to achieve than it looks.

I am calling `runOnUiThread(uiUpdaterRunnable)` from the worker thread but the delay of execution of uiUpdaterRunnable is variable and generally more than 300ms.

I tried to Use AsyncTask with publishProgress but it also gave me similar results.

How can i update UI from the worker thread to get at least 10FPS ?

Here is the runnable of my worker thread :

```
new Runnable() {
public void run() {
 try {



            int sampleRate = 44100;
            int audioFormat = AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT;
            int channelConfig = MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC;
            int bufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(sampleRate, channelConfig, audioFormat);
            audioRecorder = new AudioRecord(channelConfig, sampleRate, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO, audioFormat, bufferSize);
            if (bufferSize == AudioRecord.ERROR_BAD_VALUE)
                Log.i("AudioRecord", "AudioRecord Bad Buffer Size");
            if (audioRecorder.getState() == AudioRecord.STATE_INITIALIZED)
                Log.i("AudioRecord", "AudioRecord Initialized Successfully");

            audioRecorder.startRecording();
        while (recording) {
            startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            short[] buffer = new short[bufferSize];
            audioRecorder.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

            double[] bufferDouble = shortToDoubleArray(buffer);

            final DataPoint[] resultArray = getFFTResult(bufferDouble);


             //This is where I update UI
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                 public void run() {
                updateGraph(resultArray);
                }
            });

        }
        releaseAudioResources();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        if (e.getMessage() == null)
            e.printStackTrace();
        else
            Log.e("Exception", e.getMessage());
        releaseAudioResources();
    }
}
```

Comment: have you tried Handler to post a message when your work is done and update UI?

Comment: Yes, I tried it. It is nearly equivalent to `runOnUiThread`, handler execution is delayed too much.

Comment: You may need to look at `SurfaceView` or even `GLSurfaceView` for faster updates. This will be a significant change however to your working structure.

Comment: Dont delay it. Just post a mesage and update it. Its real time. Like mHandler.sendMessage();

Comment: nope Let me write the answer for you

Answer (score 1):

```
}
....
// write this outside your code block
 Handler mHandler = new Handler(){
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        super.handleMessage(msg);
        updateGraph(resultArray);
    }
};
// to call it inside runnable
mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
```

Comment: Update: I found out that the drop in the delay is due to re-update of startTime before the message is handled. When I corrected the code to wait until the message is being handled (i.e. UI update started), the delay is again above 300ms. So, problem not solved :(

Comment: Ok, I'll have a look then Till then you can checkout this https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/communicate-ui.html

Comment: also what you can do is Preview the UI to the user and post the the data update in that after you have completed the process. This will enhance the visual experience to the user